# Saucelabs session is not closing properly

Tags: saucelabs

Even though my test script has run successfully, I'm getting an error saying `Error closing result stream`.

Below is the body of error:

```
com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST closeInputStream
WARNING: Error closing result stream
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/myuser/jobs/ef4505aca4cf4c32a08d5d6c425fbf57
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1915)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1515)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:251)
    at com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST.closeInputStream(SauceREST.java:700)
    at com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST.updateJobInfo(SauceREST.java:643)
    at com.saucelabs.junit.SauceOnDemandTestWatcher.succeeded(SauceOnDemandTestWatcher.java:95)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher.succeededQuietly(TestWatcher.java:75)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher.access$100(TestWatcher.java:46)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:56)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at com.saucelabs.junit.ConcurrentParameterized$SauceClassRunnerForParameters.access$300(ConcurrentParameterized.java:166)
    at com.saucelabs.junit.ConcurrentParameterized$SauceClassRunnerForParameters$2.run(ConcurrentParameterized.java:283)
    at com.saucelabs.junit.ConcurrentParameterized$NonBlockingAsynchronousRunner$1.call(ConcurrentParameterized.java:308)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for this is when you're changing job status while it's still running (or has *just* been closed).

Does it happen consistently?  If you add a pause before calling the API or a single retry, do you still see this happen?